# Change text colour based on a condition in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I do NOT mean the whole text of a cell, but specific words within the same cell only.

For example, in the following example you can see a list of words. As "bbb ccc" is in that list, only the text "bbb ccc" should be coloured in red.

[image: example screenshot]

Comment: afaik this cannot be done in google sheets natively. You could create an API and return the cell content as an image, but probably an overkill

Comment: if you want to automate the process, then you need a script using `setRichTextValue` - refer the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range?hl=en#setrichtextvaluevalue). There's also an entire Class devoted to `RichTextValue` [doc](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/rich-text-value?hl=en)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That can only be done with a script. Use the [TextStyle](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-style) class. See the [formatText](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/157400260?msgid=157852265) script for sample code.

**UPDATE FROM THE AUTHOR OF THE QUESTION:**

The following should help you to code your own version. In the example above, he does the following:

```
      const specs = [
        { regex: /red/gi, textColor: 'red', bold: true, },
        { regex: /green/gi, textColor: 'green', bold: true, },
        { regex: /blue/gi, textColor: 'blue', bold: true, },
        { regex: /orange/gi, textColor: 'orange', bold: true, },
        { regex: /black/gi, textColor: 'black', bold: true, },
      ];
```

But as we want to get the values from a range, so we don't know what the text will be, I've modified that to:

```
  const colorsList = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'DeepPink', 'orange', 'purple', 'Sienna', 'MediumPurple', 'DarkTurquoise', 'DeepSkyBlue', 'Olive', 'GreenYellow', 'DarkBlue', 'Aquamarine', 'Lime', 'OrangeRed', 'DarkRed', 'Indigo',];
  const stringList = sheet.getRange('B2:B20').getDisplayValues().flat();
  const specs = [];
  stringList.forEach((string, index) => {
    specs.push({ regex: new RegExp(string, 'gi'), textColor: colorsList[index], bold: true, });
  });
```

Please note that that will work for a maximum of 18 text strings as the `colorsList` has that many different colors. To get more colors to add to the list, see [getFontColorObject()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getfontcolorobject).

Comment: After some coding, I've been able to make it work. thanks to those examples :D

Comment: Someone has modified the URL to get more colours on the answer. So this is the original URL to find more colours to add to the list: https://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_groups.asp